# Is it possible to load OGRE meshes in Ignition Gazebo

Tags: ignition-dome, mesh, ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can export OGRE meshes from blender with [blender2ogre](https://github.com/OGRECave/blender2ogre) so it seems straightforward to use them in the simulations but the sdf "mesh" tag doesn't support this format.

Is it true that I can't use the OGRE meshes in Ignition Gazebo, or I am just missing something?

The errors when I try to use

```
<geometry>
    <mesh><uri>/some/ogre.mesh</uri></mesh>
</geometry>
```

in ignition-dome:

```
$ ign gazebo test.sdf 
[GUI] [Err] [MeshManager.cc:119] Invalid mesh filename extension[/some/ogre.mesh]
[GUI] [Err] [MeshDescriptor.cc:56] Mesh manager can't find mesh named [/some/ogre.mesh]
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2MeshFactory.cc:496] Cannot load null mesh [/some/ogre.mesh]
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2MeshFactory.cc:84] Failed to get Ogre item for [/some/ogre.mesh]
[GUI] [Err] [SceneManager.cc:335] Failed to load geometry for visual: visual
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25995/is-it-possible-to-load-ogre-meshes-in-ignition-gazebo/) by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Interesting, I had never seen that file format.

Ignition Gazebo currently only supports these mesh formats:

- COLLADA
- OBJ (+ MTL)
- STL

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1